# 2d Perlin noise. Why do i have to take the dotproduct of displacement and gradientvector?

Tags: c#, math, perlin-noise

Taking [this](http://webstaff.itn.liu.se/~stegu/TNM022-2005/perlinnoiselinks/perlin-noise-math-faq.html) into account, i do not understand why i have to take the dotproduct of the gradient vector and the displacement of my point to it. Can anyone explain me why i have to do that? I actually understand [this](http://freespace.virgin.net/hugo.elias/models/m_perlin.htm) tutorial, where they just took a simple blur to calculate the value of the grid point (called smooth noise). The linear interpolation is in both cases clear to me. So can anyone explain me why they take the dotproduct of the displacement and so called "gradientvector" in the first tutorial? What effect has it?

Comment: That first link seems to be about different ways of sub-sampling a field -- which slightly misses the point of Perlin noise (which is multiple scales of noise summed together). So the dot-product isn't *required*, but you can use it if you take a geometric view of the subsampling.

Comment: isn't that fractal noise, when u add many noises with different octaves together?

Comment: It's not really fractal, as it has no self similarity at different scales. It's just multiple summed frequencies of noise.

Comment: so if i generate my noise with a for lope wich counts my octaves i can just skip the step, where i take the dotproduct? 
http://code.google.com/p/fractalterraingeneration/wiki/Perlin_Noise
here they say i have to do both. Fractal and perlin noise with the procedure from above O.o

Comment: It's up to you how you get your results (unless you're on a course ;-) The most clear description I've ever seen is from the old bouncy-stretchy page: http://freespace.virgin.net/hugo.elias/models/m_perlin.htm

Comment: you are wrong by the way ;) the first one is perlin noise and the 2nd misses the point since it is value noise. Just to solve the confusion here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok i figured it out myself now. The first tutorials noise is a so called gradient noise, while the second tutorials one is a value noise. The classic perlin noise by ken is a gradient noise (better quality and performance) while the value noise is easier to understand. But in both cases octaves are added together n times(the gradient noise doesnt replace this procedure).
See:

http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_noise

http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_noise

Gradient noise seeds a grid with random vectors of the length 1. These vectors are placed with a distance of 1 to each other.  Taking the dotproduct of the displacementvector from the 4 nearest gridpoints to my wanted point and the seeded gradient vectors at these 4 points will then result in a value between -1 and 1 for each of these 4 points. These values can then be interpolated to get the actual points value.

Value noise generates random values in real time for every gridpoint, wich are placed with a distance between them of 1. These values are generated with a seed, wich allowS me to get the same value over and over again. When i pick my square wich surrounds my point i want to get, i generate the random value in realtion to my passed coordinates (the algorithm for such a generator can be seen in the 2nd tut)  and then blur it with the surrounding gridpoints to get a smooth noise.